# MySQL Unknown column Error, but Column exists

Tags: mysql, select

I'm getting this error:

`Unknown column 'TTFFdata.product_id' in 'where clause'`

using this query in phpmyadmin:

`select product_name from product where product.product_id=TTFFdata.product_id`

What I don't understand is that `TTFFdata.product_id` DOES exist, and is highlighted in blue in the SQL query editor, as well as offered as an autocomplete option.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: TTFFdata is what? A table?

Comment: Yes, a table with a column called product_id. This works: `select product_id from TTFFdata where 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use another table to retrieve your data, so you should join them:

```
select product.product_name 
from product
join TTFFdata on product.product_id = TTFFdata.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare two columns with each other use JOIN.

Thanks